# rotating and exchanging x for y's in regression

Tags: regression

I was just wondering what happens generally if i send all my x points to y's and y's to x's (i.e reflect along the y=x line) - if I change the x's and y's will my old error minimizing line still be the error minimizing line after reflection? How about if I rotate points?

Many thanks

Comment: A two variable (1 RHS, 1 LHS) setup like this: $y = \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon$? What do you mean by rotate, something like this? $z = \zeta + \iota w + \xi$, where z and w are linear combinations of x and y (e.g. $w = \psi x + \phi y)$?

Answer (score 5):

This is a somewhat "dated" subject in introductory econometrics, I suspect because, in econometrics the models come from theories and arguments that try to a priori establish causality and not just association.

Anyway, the issue is analyzed in [Maddala's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._S._Maddala) Econometrics [textbook](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP000871.html).

In the 2001 3d ed. the issue for simple regression is presented in ch. 3. inside section 3.4, under the title **"Reverse Regression"**.

Writing

$$\hat y = \hat a + \hat b x,$$
and

$$\hat x = \hat a' + \hat b'y$$

one can quickly find that

$$\hat b \hat b' = r^2_{xy}$$

i.e. the product of the two is equal to the squared correlation between $x$ and $y$. If this correlation coefficient is close to unity then the two regression lines will be close.

One can also establish a relation between the two constant terms easily.